# Which did come first morality or Judicial Law System?

Tags: ethics

Did Judicial Law System mold our morality or our moral sense or ethics or moral compass build up our Federal, Provincial, and City Council law system?

Which did come first?

Comment: Considering that the [basis of morality is biological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_of_morality) the answer should be obvious. Not that the law did not provide feedback influence on cultural development of moral norms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Morality clearly came far before the law. In fact, at the time life first experienced morality, they could not even create laws, much less a judicial system. The first known judicial system was in Egypt, based on Ma'at, 5000 years ago. Morality, with its biological nature, most likely came millions of years ago. So morality did come first, and laws being based on Ma'at (truth, order, morality, etc. ) is proof morality molded the law, not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can answer this in opposite ways at different levels of abstraction from the notions of evolutionary psychology.

@MathBob is right.  Clearly morality comes before the Law in a concrete, historical sense.  A lot of our moral principles, like fairness, seem to be inborn and to be shared to some degree with related species.  Submissive simians sometimes express distaste at dominant members' unfairness, and they may correct for their own previous unfairness.  So humans probably had incipient morals before they had statable laws.

But in a more abstract sense, the opposite is true.  Judgement by others precedes the sense of individual morality.  We can see the point at which our children start to treat the adults around them as people with preferences (feeding adults, for instance, things they know they like) comes before they internalize the notion of rules they should obey (acting overly cute or shy when they know they are doing something that is regularly prevented, and being excited (often to the point they are immobilized) by the contradiction implicit in breaking a rule.)  From an 'ontogeny recapitulates phylogeny' point of view, we can then assume that these things most likely first affected our biology and our cultures in the same order.

So the odds are this is a spiral of development.  Group preferences shaped our conscience, and individuals shared the resulting expectations, which becames a group activity that shaped all the members' conscience...  Morality shapes Law, which evolves Morality, leading to better Law.

Answer (score 0):

Examples can be found for laws being molded by morality, laws being molded by other things (politics, economics), and morals being molded by such laws that were not molded by morality. Also examples can be found for laws emerging that contradict morality of the time, and of morality to emerge that contradicts laws of a given time.

So laws and morality influence each other, but both have other influences too, and they are not necessarily compatible.

So the question seems to wrongly generalize that either all laws must have been molded by morality or the other way round. Instead, one would have to analyze for each given law or aspect of morality to find out the factors that led to their creation individually.